# Expiring Enterprise Distribution Profile Cannot Be Renewed

Tags: xcode, profile, enterprise, provisioning

On the Organizer Library we have the list of Provisioning Profiles. Here I have a my enterprise distribution profile that is about to expire (2 days) And it has a button that says  "Renew" next to it.
When I click on the button, I get the next Error Message:

> ***The given provisioning profile has no associated devices and cannot be renewed.**
>   Please add devices to your provisioning profile before attempting to renew “enterprise”, or create a new provisioning profile.*

I have tried to add random devices to the profile by right clicking on them and selecting "Add Device to Provisional Portal", but it doesn't seem to work. It just adds the device on the Developer iOS Provisioning Portal Devices list. But the profile associated to this device its not my distribution profile, it's one called:

> iOS Team Provisioning Profile:* Xcode: iOS Wildcard AppID

And I cannot modify it through the ADP to change the profile. But I don't think that is the answer. 
Now, the thing is that I have about 1 thousand users and I would prefer not to create a new profile to recompile my apps and then ask them to download them again.

**Is there a way I can renew this profile without all the pain?**

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting can be misleading "The given provisioning profile has no associated devices and cannot be renewed. "   With enterprise profile you need to add device only for Developer Profile not for Distribution. This is why you do not have a device limitation with distribution.  I do not think expiring profile will affect existing user who uses your application currently but anyway you have to renew your profile in the end. My suggestion will be deleting and recreating it.